# java String.format - how to put a space between two characters

Tags: string.format

I am searching for a way to use a formatter to put a space between two characters.  i thought it would be easy with a string formatter.

here is what i am trying to accomplish:

given: "AB" it will produce "A B"

Here is what i have tried so far:

```
"AB".format("%#s")
```

but this keep returning "AB" i want "A B". i thought the number sign could be used for space.

i also tried this:

```
"26".format("%#d") but its still prints "26"
```

is there anyway to do this with string.formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind of possible with the string formatter although not directly with a pattern.

```
jshell> String.format("%1$c %2$c", "AB".chars().boxed().toArray())
$10 ==> "A B"
```

We need to turn the string into an object array so it can be passed in as varargs and the formatter pattern can extract characters based on index (`1$` and `2$`) and format them as characters (`c`).

A much simpler regex solution is the following which scales to any number of characters:

```
jshell> "ABC^&*123".replaceAll(".", "$0 ").trim()
$3 ==> "A B C ^ & * 1 2 3"
```

All single characters are replaced with them-self (`$0`) followed by a space. Then the last extra space is removed with the `trim()` call.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find way to do this using `String#format`.  But here is a way to accomplish this using regex replacement:

```
String input = "AB";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])", " ");
System.out.println(output);
```

The regex pattern `(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])` will match every position in between two capital letters, and interpolate a space at that point.  The above script prints:

```
A B
```

Comment: how do i include digits. it should be any kind of character.

Comment: Use the regex pattern `(?<=.)(?=.)` to add a space between any two characters.